# React Navigation: What does goBack(null) do?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation module, and using goBack() function to close current page and navigate previous page. All params and instances must be deleted while screen is navigating.  In documentation they say : 
'Optionally provide a key, which specifies the route to go back from. By default, goBack will close the route that it is called from. If the goal is to go back anywhere, without specifying what is getting closed, call .goBack(null);

'What does it means? What will be changed if I use goBack(null) instead of goBack()? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're not nesting navigators, there's no difference at all. If you have one navigator inside another, goBack() only works for root navigator direct children (switching between them), so in my opnion it's better to use goBack(null).

Comment: In my case, I built my nav components like this: Stacks > One of stacks is DrawerNav > Inside Drawer, there is a TabNav which has 2 screens. What will happen if I use goBack() or goBack(null) in one of TabNavs?

Comment: I think goBack()  won't work and goBack(null) will get you back to DrawerNav's main screen.